# jQuery click function not working on accordion menu link

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.pharmacies-module-title-class').click(function(){
    console.log('heloooo');
  });
});
```

That given class is a `jquery ui` accordion opening link and I'd like to add a class to it when the accordion is open, but this script doesn't work. Why is that?

Comment: Is the accordion menu part of the page when it loads, or is it shown to the user after the page has loaded?

Can you show us the HTML markup of the menu?

Comment: I think you should add a fiddle of the code that's not working, as there's nothing wrong with the code you put on here.

Comment: downvoted for lack of html markup or fiddle. Please provide the missing component which others are asking and I will remove my downvote

Answer (score 0):

Hey Please try that code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('body').on('click', '.pharmacies-module-title-class', function () {
      console.log('heloooo');
 });
});
```

Comment: Then surely the key hidden in your markup.please share your markup